# Excel: How to Compare Column Values in a Row

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a bunch of comparison data and a lot of entries being compared. As an example, say my sheet looks like this, give or take a few columns:

```
Item   Price1    Quantity1    Price2    Quantity2    Price3    Quantity3
001    $123      12           $456      24           $789      48
002    $100      95           $200      5            $300      51
```

For each item (row), I want to be able to look at all of the Quantity columns and find which one has the highest quantity. Ideally I'd be able to run a condition of some sort on the entire excel sheet at once, and it would highlight in red the highest quantity.

So the results would be a red "48" (qty3) for Item 001 and a red "95" (qty1) for Item 002.

Only the color would change, not any data, and no new rows would need to be created.

Let me know if you need more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use conditional formatting. Starting in cell C2 (if your data starts in A1), use this formula

```
=C2=MAX($C2,$E2,$G2)
```

[image]

Mind the placement of the $ signs!!

Then copy C2 and use paste special > Formats to paste the conditional format to other cells or whole columns.